# The conversion of nvarchar value "0854697543" overflowed an int column in select command

Tags: sql, selectcommand

I have a select command, and it returns answer records, but it also gives an error in  Visual Studio 2010's query builder with this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Orders
WHERE   (BCode = 025) AND (Date BETWEEN '1390%' AND '1391%') OR
        (Date BETWEEN '1390%' AND '1391%') AND (MCode = 0123456789)
```

The error is:

> Error Message: the conversion of nvarchar value "0854697543"
>   overflowed an int column

Data types are

```
BCode : nvarchar(50)
Date :  nvarchar(50)
MCode : nvarchar(10)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us in which field is present `0854697543` value? And why do you use `nvarchar` for dates?

Comment: And why are you storing a date value as `nvarchar(50)` ??

Comment: What is the `BETWEEN '1390%' AND '1391%'` meant to do? As the '%' wildcard operator does not apply in the `BETWEEN` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
AND (MCode = '0123456789')
```

?

Otherwise it will try to use 0123456789 as an integer which will lead to the conversion error.

In addition, you're repeating yourself in the logic (`Date BETWEEN...`), more concise:

```
WHERE   (Date BETWEEN '1390%' AND '1391%') AND
        ((BCode = 025) OR (MCode = '0123456789'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand where the problem is: you're comparing `MCode` (which is a `nvarchar`) with an integer value (`0123456789`) in your query, so engine is trying to convert your field to int for every record!!
Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Orders
WHERE   (BCode = '025') AND 
        (LEFT(Date, 4) = '1390' OR LEFT(Date, 4) = '1391') AND 
        (MCode = '0123456789')
```

As I've already told you in my comment: don't use `nvarchar(50)` to store dates!! Use appropriate data type (DateTime or Date for example) for every column: it will avoid headaches in future, makes query design easier and makes query execution really faster!

Comment: @hamze: see my edited answer to _correct_ a lot of errors you have in your query!